# Node / Express - Refactoring Routes

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following node / express code;

```
// Requires
var app     = require("express")();
var handler = require("./routes/session");

// Routes
app.post("/session", handler.sessionGetNew);
app.get("/session", handler.sessionGetAll);
app.get("/session/:sessionid", handler.sessionGetOne);
app.put("/session/:sessionid", handler.sessionUpdate);
app.delete("/session/:sessionid", handler.sessionDelete);

// Listener
app.listen(9000);

console.log("Listening.....");
```

Is there any way to refactor the routes to something like this pseudcode?

```
app.route("/session"),
  .post(handler.session....)
  .get(handler.session.....)

app.route("/session/:sessionid"),
  .post(handler.session....)
  .get(handler.session....)
  .put(handler.session....)
```

Comment: What's wrong with your "pseudocode"? That's the correct code. http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.route

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't do anything;

`app.route('/session')
  .get(function(req, res, next) {
    handler.sessionGetAll;
  })
  .post(function(req, res, next) {
    handler.sessionNew;
});`

Comment: you're not calling the functions there. Just do the same thing as in your original code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Router Middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router)

**app.js**

```
var app     = require('express')();
var session = require('./routes/session');

app.use('/session', session);

app.listen(9000, function() {
  console.log('listening');
});
```

**routes/session.js**

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var handler = require('./lib/sessionHandler'); // this was 'handler' in app.js

router.post('/', handler.sessionGetNew);
router.get('/', handler.sessionGetAll);

router.get('/:sessionid', handler.sessionGetOne);
router.put('/:sessionid', handler.sessionUpdate);
router.delete('/:sessionid', handler.sessionDelete);

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you approximately what you want

```
function routReductor(route, methods) {
  var goodMethods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'];
  for (var key in methods) {
    if (goodMethods.indexOf(key) == -1) continue;
    app[key](route, methods[key])
  }
}

routReductor('/:sessionid', {
  get: handler.sessionGetOne,
  put: handler.sessionUpdate,
  delete: handler.sessionDelete
});
```